# Can the condition given to takeWhile function contain or operator?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to compute the value

```
takeWhile (/="E"||/="A") ls
```

where

```
ls = ["EVENT","6010","A","CHECK_PROMOTION_ELIGIBLE","-1","E","RUN_EVENT","6020"]
```

However, ghci complines as

> ```
> Variable not in scope: (||/=) :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
> ```

Is there a syntax problem, or just can't we use `||` operator while specifying to condition for `takeWhile` function ?

I have tried to remove the *||/="A"* part, then there is no error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible that way. First of all, you made a syntax error: by writing `(/="E"||/="A")` Haskell sees the `||/=` part as a *single* operator.

We can fix the syntax error, and write:

```
takeWhile ((/="E") || (/="A")) ls
```

But this is still invalid, since `||` expects *two* `Bool`eans, and here the operands are `String -> Bool`s.

Nevertheless we can solve this, for example with a *lambda* expression:

```
takeWhile (\x -> (x /="E") || (x /="A")) ls
```

There is also a *semantical* error. A test like `x /= c1 || x /= c2` where `c1 /= c2` is *always* `True`. Indeed. The first test fails in case `x == c1`, but if `c1 /= c2`, then we know that `x /= c2`, hence it would always result in `True`. So you probably want to use:

```
takeWhile (\x -> ( x/="E") && (/="A")) ls
```

we can also use the [**`notElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:notElem) function, which makes the code more self explaining:

```
takeWhile (`notElem` ["A", "E"]) ls
```

or with [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

```
takeWhile (flip notElem ["A", "E"]) ls
```

Comment: what is the reason for the backstricks ? What are their function ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: to write it as an *infix* operator, such that `["A", "E"]` is seen as the *second* parameter, and we thens till need to provide the first, but we can use `flip` as well.

Comment: `(||) <$> (/= "A") <*> (/= "E")` but actually as written, the simplest way is `const True`, so the question is probably wrong.

Comment: @dfeuer: well I think using a `Functor` will probably only confuse most readers. But you are correct that there was a semantical error (somehow I've overlooked that). This should now be fixed (and documented).

Comment: The `Functor` approach doesn't really require fully understanding *why* functions are functors, though. Knowing that `(&&) a b` is another way to write `a && b` is a good start, and pretending that `(&&) <$> f <*> g` is just syntactic sugar for `\x -> (&&) (f x) (g x)` will get you pretty far.